# client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-lambda

I have a lambda written in Go that communicates with a lightweight http app behind an application load balancer in AWS:

```
package main

import (
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    for {
        req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "http://my-app-12345.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com:8080", nil)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal("Error reading request. ", err)
        }

        req.Header.Set("Load-Rate", os.Getenv("LOAD"))

        client := &http.Client{Timeout: time.Second * 10}

        resp, err := client.Do(req)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal("Error reading response. ", err)
        }
        if resp.StatusCode == http.StatusOK {
            bodyBytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
            bodyString := string(bodyBytes)
            log.Println(bodyString)
        }

        time.Sleep(time.Duration(10) * time.Millisecond)
    }
}
```

I've opened worldwide access on all ports in the security groups being used by both the lambda and the ALB and I can curl the endpoint fine from my home machine. However, when I attempt to run this in Lambda, I get the following in my CloudWatch logs:

> 2020-06-04T07:06:31.028-05:00 Process exited before completing
>   request
>   2020-06-04T07:06:41.100-05:00      2020/06/04 12:06:41 Error
>   reading response. Get
>   http://my-app-12345.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com:8080:
>   net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection
>   (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
>   2020-06-04T07:06:41.101-05:00      2020/06/04 12:06:41 exit status 1

I'm having  a hard time figuring out if this is a Go issue or some configuration I have wrong in AWS. I'm not very familiar at all with the error Go is throwing here.

Comment: Just like the error says, the request timed out. There's not much we can guess from that, other than it took more than the 10 seconds you gave it, probably because it still can't connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You lambda seems to be in VPC since you write about its **security groups**. If this is the case then the most likely reason for the timeout is that **lambda in VPC does not have internet access nor public IP**, even if its in public subnet.

From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc.html):

> Connecting a function to a public subnet does not give it internet access or a public IP address.

Since your ALB is public (you curl it from home) your lambda can't access it, even if they are both in the same subnet.

To rectify this you would have to setup **NAT gateway or instance** with correct routes to be able to communicate from lambda in VPC to your public ALB, and place your lambda in a **private subnet**.

Comment: Thank you, I do have  NAT gateway but maybe there's something I need to add - they are all associated with public subnets. Right now my ALB has 2 private and 1 public subnet attached (the public remaining so I can test from home). My Lambda has the same 2 private subnets attached.

Comment: @MrDuk When you created your ALB, have you chosen internet-facing or internal? It seems you have internet-facing as you curl if from home. Thus it **must** be in public subnets. Have you configured route tables for the private subnets to route internet traffic to NAT gateway in public subnet?